# Which of the Death Eaters survive after the final battle?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

So after the final battle, lots of people die.

But not everyone! Even people from the bad side had to have survived.

So who did?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It is hard to know which Death Eaters survived because we do not know all their names**. Many of the deaths, specifically in the Battle of Hogwarts, are anonymous. We can possibly extrapolate notable survivors with a list of Death Eaters who were killed.

One will notice that Voldemort's and the Death Eaters' kill count is *way* higher than the Harry/Dumbledore/Order of the Phoenix's. However, that would be expected since we have a classic "good vs. evil" story.

Many other families to be known Death Eaters (and first names not always known) and were not to be shown killed outright.

---

---

### [Notable Survivors:](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Eaters)

**The Malfoy Family**: Lucius, Narcissa, and Draco were seen fleeing the Battle of Hogwarts.

**The Carrows:** Alceto and Amycus were tied-up in the Ravenclaw Tower prior to the Battle of Hogwarts.

**Antonin Dolohov:** Was defeated but not killed by Professor Flitwich during the Battle of Hogwarts.

**Augustus Rookwood:** Sent to Azkaban after the Department of Mysteries incident, but escaped during mass break out.

**Walden Macnair:** Hagrid slammed him into a wall during the Battle of Hogwarts, but he was only knocked unconscious.

---

---

### [Death Eaters that were killed:](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_deaths)

**Prior to the Battle of Hogwarts:**

**Evan Rosier:** killed while resisting capture before Lord Voldemort's downfall by Alastor Moody (mentioned in *GoF*)

**Wilkes:** killed while resisting capture before Lord Voldemort's downfall by Aurors (mentioned in *GoF*)

**Gibbon:** killed by a stray Killing Curse cast by Thorfinn Rowle (*HBP*)

**Regulus Black** (reformed): Killed while attempting to destroy the locket Horcrux.   (mentioned in *DH*)

**Barty Crouch Jr.:** Soul removed by a Dementor (*GoF*)

**Igor Karkaroff:** Killed by Voldemort for abandoning the cause.

**Peter Pettigrew:** Killed by his own magical prosthetic hand, thus Lord Voldemort, indirectly. (*DH*)

**"Several Death Eaters":**  They were not named. All killed during Voldemort's fit of rage after being informed that Helga Hufflepuff's Cup, which was one of his Horcruxes was stolen. (*DH*)

---

**During the Battle of Hogwarts:**

**Scabior:** Killed by Neville Longbottom with a collapsing bridge.

**Vincent Crabbe:** Killed by his overactive Fiendfyre.

**Severus Snape** (reformed): Killed by Nagini/Voldemort for control of the Elder Wand.

**Nagini** (animal): Killed by Neville Longbottom with the Sword of Gryffindor.

**Bellatrix Lestrange**, nee Black: Killed by Molly Weasley with an unspecified curse.

**Voldemort:** Killed by his own rebounding curse (or Harry Potter from a "certain point of view").

Comment: I believe Goyle also  survived.

Comment: Nott senior and Yaxley might have also survived, seeing there's no mention of their deaths.