# How many Death Eaters died in total?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

We know about the fifty Hogwarts fighters that died but what about the Death Eaters?

Except for Regulus Black, Severus Snape, Bellatrix and Voldemort, which Death Eaters died?

Comment: Are you asking for a number, or for a list of specific Death Eaters that died? And are you asking about a specific battle/war about all of history?

Comment: Related/Possible Dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/134733/57310

Comment: @Skooba wouldn't [Who was more likely to die, a Death Eater or Order of the Phoenix member?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9446/98028) be a better dupe? Kevin's answer lists pretty much every known death, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

### During the Dark Lord’s first rise to power:

#### Rosier and Wilkes

Both Rosier and Wilkes were killed by Aurors.

> “Sirius held up his fingers, and began ticking off names. ‘Rosier and Wilkes – they were both killed by Aurors the year before Voldemort fell.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27 (Padfoot Returns)*</sup></sub>

### During the Dark Lord’s absence, none died.

The Dark Lord mentions that three Death Eaters died in his service (presumably Rosier and Wilkes are included in that) but he doesn’t mention any having died during his absence.

> “And here we have six missing Death Eaters … three dead in my service. One, too cowardly to return … he will pay. One, who I believe has left me for ever … he will be killed, of course … and one, who remains my most faithful servant, and who has already re-entered my service.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

### During the Dark Lord’s second rise to power:

#### Barty Crouch Jr.

Barty Crouch Jr. died when kissed by a Dementor.

> “The moment that – that thing entered the room,’ she screamed, pointing at Fudge, trembling all over, ‘it swooped down on Crouch and – and –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 36 (The Parting of the Ways)*</sup></sub>

#### Igor Karkaroff

Igor Karkaroff was killed by the Death Eaters, or the Dark Lord himself, for deserting them.

> “And they’ve found Igor Karkaroff’s body in a shack up north. The Dark Mark had been set over it – well, frankly, I’m surprised he stayed alive for even a year after deserting the Death Eaters; Sirius’s brother Regulus only managed a few days as far as I can remember.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 6 (Draco’s Detour)*</sup></sub>

#### Gibbon

Gibbon died when he was hit by a Killing Curse aimed at Remus Lupin.

> “But I don’t think Gibbon liked the idea of waiting up there alone for Dumbledore, because he came running back downstairs to rejoin the fight and was hit by a Killing Curse that just missed me.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 29 (The Phoenix Lament)*</sup></sub>